# Ruby on Rails FactoryGirl not generating factory with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

My student_status id's store different associations.  For instance, student_status_id of 1 means the student is active, so it is integral that I generate these different id's.  I've tried creating a FactoryGirl user without the student_status_id 1 and the code breaks telling me that there is no status_id.  Furthermore, how do I use FactoryGirl to generate say a status_id  of say 7?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name 'example'
    last_name 'user'
    email 'example@user.com'
    username 'example'
    password 'abcdef'
    password_confirmation 'abcdef'
    birthdate DateTime.new(1990,9,1,17)
    student
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student_status do
    name 'Active'
    student
  end  
end    

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
    points 20
    session_minutes 120
    weekly_session_minutes 120
    can_schedule_self false
    next_monthly_cycle DateTime.new(2015,9,1,17)
    student_status_id 1
  end
end
```

Here are the tables defined in my schema

```
  create_table "student_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "lesson_id"
    t.integer  "points"
    t.integer  "student_status_id"
    t.date     "next_monthly_cycle"
    t.integer  "session_minutes",        default: 0,    null: false
    t.date     "next_session_minutes"
    t.date     "next_session_schedule"
    t.integer  "weekly_session_minutes", default: 0,    null: false
    t.boolean  "can_schedule_self",      default: true, null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a 1:1 association, e.g. `student_id` in the `student_status` table, and `student_status_id` in the `students` table at the same time?

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory(:student) do
    points 20
    session_minutes 120
    weekly_session_minutes 120
    can_schedule_self false
    next_monthly_cycle DateTime.new(2015,9,1,17)
    association(:status, factory: :student_status)
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory(:student_status) do
    name { ['Active', 'Inactive', 'SomeOther'].sample }
  end
end
```

Also, make sure you have this in the `Student` class:

```
belongs_to :student_status
```

Afterwards, try this from the rails console:

```
FactoryGirl.load
student = FactoryGirl.create(:student)
puts student.status # => should return actual random status
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion there, student belongs to `student_status`, will this generate that association?

Comment: @KevinBehan can you update you question with the exact schema you have? Specifically student/student_statuses tables. Asking this since from looking at the factories you've provided, you have 1:1 association.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I have a method that is called when the create action is used in the StudentsController that is contingent upon the student_status_id.  It checks if a student is enrolled, `student_status.enrolled?`, and the test console is telling me  `NoMethodError: undefined method `enrolled?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I don't have `belongs_to :student_status`, I instead of `belongs_to :status, class_name: 'StudentStatus'`. That's what's throwing me off